# DEBUG vs RELEASE and distributing Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-compilation

I am creating and distributing an assembly for other developers to use.
I am distributing the Release version of my assembly (not the debug).
In one of the classes of my assembly, I have code set to run only in Debug mode using

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("Release");
#endif
```

If other developers reference my Assembly from their project and run their project in Debug mode, will my Debug only conditional run or not?

Comment: If you distribute the RELEASE version of your code it is impossible because that code has been stripped away by the compiler at build time

Comment: They're pre-compiler statements. So they a processed at compile time. So the non-debug version will be removed from the assembly when it's compiled.

Comment: This is an XY problem. Use `Debugger.IsAttached` to do a runtime check. Slightly different semantics, but perhaps this is what you want? Can't say for sure, the question is underspecified.

Comment: It depends on the executable they add to the project.  If another project use your assembly they are adding the dll from the bin folder.  The bin folder will have both a Release and Debug Folder.  So it depends on which folder they use.

Comment: @jdw No it doesn't. He says he's only distributing the "Release" version.

Comment: Then should build with map in dll so code can be debugged.

Comment: @CodyGray _"Use Debugger.IsAttached to do a runtime check"_ - well that doesn't prove anything.  `Debugger.IsAttached` can still return `false` even in a _debug_ build

Comment: Of course it can, @micky. What it proves is that the debugger is attached. Notice that I did say "slightly different semantics"? As I said, this is almost certainly an XY problem, so I was trying to guess at what might be wanted.

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps, but the question is flagged `conditional-compilation`  after-all.

Comment: @micky I tagged it that.

Comment: @CodyGray So you did lol.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If other developers reference my Assembly from their project and run their project in Debug mode, will my Debug only conditional run or not ?

No, because the `Console.WriteLine()` was never compiled in **Release** mode due to the pre-processor constraint.

MSDN has more to say on this:

> When the C# compiler encounters an `#if` directive, followed eventually by an `#endif` directive, it will compile the code between the directives **only if the specified symbol is defined** ... [Tell me more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Also, it's not correct to think of it as being removed from the assembly as it was never present in the first place.